# Inserting fields with linebreaks between them

Tags: vba, field, ms-word

I'm trying to insert a series of Word fields based on the content of a simple text file, however when I run this code it inserts all of the fields together and clumps all of the linebreaks after all of the fields instead of inserting a linebreak in-between each field. Pray tell, what am I doing wrong?

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddFields()

    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = InputBox("Filename containing field list")

    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fileStream As Scripting.TextStream
    Set fileStream = fso.OpenTextFile(fileName, ForReading, False)

    Dim line As String
    While Not fileStream.AtEndOfStream
        line = fileStream.ReadLine

        Selection.Range.InsertBreak WdBreakType.wdLineBreak

        AddField line

    Wend

End Sub

Sub AddField(mergeFieldName As String)

    Dim fieldText As String
    fieldText = "MERGEFIELD  " & mergeFieldName & " "

    ActiveDocument.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:=fieldText, PreserveFormatting:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a good explanation as well.

Both of these work if you put them instead of your InsertBreak line:

```
Selection.InsertBreak WdBreakType.wdTextWrappingBreak 

Selection.TypeParagraph
```

The first has a slightly different meaning (see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdbreaktype(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdbreaktype%28v=office.14%29.aspx)) but it looks OK in the context of your script. The second one is what word does when I record a macro and type text

Comment: Perfect, `InsertBreak wdTextWrappingBreak` does the job perfectly, thanks!